# column does not exist is postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Here is my sql data. 
When I execute this query in postgresql getting some error.
Please help me to correct this. I have no experience in this database.

```
-- ----------------------------
--  Sequence structure for tuning_id_seq
-- ----------------------------
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS "mainpage"."tuning_id_seq";
CREATE SEQUENCE "mainpage"."tuning_id_seq" INCREMENT 1 START 4000 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 MINVALUE 1 CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE "mainpage"."tuning_id_seq" OWNER TO "postgres";
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for tuning
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "mainpage"."tuning";
CREATE TABLE "mainpage"."tuning" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval("tuning_id_seq"::regclass),
    "motor_id" int4,
    "speed" int4,
    "freetext" varchar(200) COLLATE "default",
    "date_create" varchar(30) COLLATE "default",
    "date_change" varchar(30) COLLATE "default"
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "mainpage"."tuning" OWNER TO "postgres";

-- ----------------------------
--  Records of tuning
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO "mainpage"."tuning" VALUES ('1', '1', '0', null, null, null);
INSERT INTO "mainpage"."tuning" VALUES ('2', '2', '0', null, null, null);
INSERT INTO "mainpage"."tuning" VALUES ('3', '3', '0', null, null, null);
COMMIT;
```

**Error**

```
NOTICE:  table "tuning" does not exist, skipping


ERROR:  column "tuning_id_seq" does not exist
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "tuning_id_seq" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is you need to **schema-qualify** your *sequence* name.

e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE "mainpage"."tuning" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval("mainpage"."tuning_id_seq"::regclass),
    "motor_id" int4,
    "speed" int4,
    "freetext" varchar(200) COLLATE "default",
    "date_create" varchar(30) COLLATE "default",
    "date_change" varchar(30) COLLATE "default"
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "mainpage"."tuning" OWNER TO "postgres";
```

Without the qualification, *Postgres* will look for the sequence in the `public` (e.g. unqualified) schema. (Since you could, in theory, have a sequence by the same name in each schema).